# OSX Server Monuntain Lion working as PDC

Tags: mac-osx-server, domain-controller

I have read documents about mountain lion doesn't work as PDC as previous versions Line Snow  Leopard does. I know there are various post/webs/documents talking about it but the information is very confusing.

I would like to create a PDC on OSX Mountain Lion to login 15 OSX and about 5 Windows. Is it possible using OSX Server Mountain lion out of the box?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible. Apple removed Samba in favor of it's own, much more limited CIFS implementation in 10.7. This variant is not able to work as a PDC, it's just a CIFS/SMB file server.

Rumor has it the reason is a licensing switch the Samba team did after Samba 3.0.26 (IIRC) which made it unfeasible for Apple to continue to incorporate it into MacOS.

Comment: What do you think about install an old Snow Leopard server to get PDC? or is it better go to windows PDC directly?

Comment: Use Samba on Linux or Windows Server. MacOS 10.6 is out of maintenance and the ancient Samba it includes doesn't work well with Win > XP. Also, there is no point to *start* a system with obsolete software.

Comment: To expand on SvW's "obsolete" comment: Windows NT-style PDCs were obsoleted by Active Directory with the release of Windows 2000 -- that's thirteen years ago!

Comment: A was wondering.... and it's possible to create a simply AD (active directory)? ( I have no much idea about windows world :)

Comment: @RuBiCK No, you can absolutely not create an [Active Directory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Directory) with MacOS Server. Not with older versions and certainly not with the new Fileserver-only CIFS implementation of 10.7 and newer. Integrating Mac and Windows is no longer a functionality of MacOS, your only semi-easy option in that regards is to set up a Windows Server and connect both Macs and Win systems to it. Other options exist but they require an extensive amount of knowledge and experience to get them working.